# Set value for distortion coefficient in CameraInfo

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working with 2 stereo cameras and I wish to publish their information
on ROS topics (`sensor_msgs/Image` and `sensor_msgs/CameraInfo` ) for using the [stereo_img_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc?distro=lunar) package.

I can publish my stereo camera images the sensor_msgs/Image but I am missing one component
for the other one, ie `sensors_msgs::CameraInfo` message/object.

From the online documentation for [CameraInfo.msg message](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html), the distortion array D is declared as

```
float64[] D;
```

My current attempt does this -

```
      sensor_msgs::CameraInfo caminfo; 
       cv::FileStorage fs; // using OpenCV to read YAML file 
    
// read parameters as openCV cv::Mat and then fill array
       cv::Mat D1;
       fs["distortion_coefficients"] >> D1;
       caminfo.D[0] = D1.at<double>(0,0);
       caminfo.D[1] = D1.at<double>(0,1);
       caminfo.D[2]= D1.at<double>(0,2);
       caminfo.D[3] = D1.at<double>(0,3);
       caminfo.D[4] =D1.at<double>(0,4);
```

However, this does not work and I get an **error ( Segmentation Fault core dumped** ) on running the node/executable.
This is probably because I'm making assumptions on the distortion array length but in reality I'm not aware of where the length is defined , since it is not given even [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html),

**My Question:**
Can someone please explain how to fill in the distortion matrix parameter for sensor_msgs::CameraInfo ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283828/set-value-for-distortion-coefficient-in-camerainfo/) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look in sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h, you find the declaration of D:

```
   typedef std::vector<double, typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind<double>::other >  _D_type;
  _D_type D;
```

It's a vector, so you will have to to a caminfo.D.push_back(...). (or resize the vector before writing into it).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-27**:
The D1 mat also ought to be checked for size, if for some reason it isn't five columns then there will also be a segfault.